# Two Unit Tests with two different App.config execute together

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, app-config

I have one Test Projekt called "Project A Test" and a second called "Project B Test".
Both have a different App.config File.
When i run both Tests together it seems that only the first alphabetical App.config is used => Project A Test App.config (also for the second Project).
When i rename Project A Test to Project C Test the App.config from Project B will be used.
I have my NHibernate Session information in the App.config and need to connect to different Databases for the two Projects.

How can i say to the NUnit Test Framework to use the App.config from their own projects?

Comment: Do you have a config file in your test project folder named as your project? For example: ProjectA.nunit and ProjectA.config

Comment: They should by default. Double check your `bin\Debug` folder - what config file do you have after Visual Studio *Rebuild*? Do you have any app.config transformations? BTW you aren't running *unit* tests, it's more like  *integration* tests.

Comment: Both config files are called App.config

Comment: When i look into bin\Debug folder both have their own App.config file so here it is ok. But NUnit use just the first for both

Comment: Take a look at this blog: http://blog.coryfoy.com/2005/08/nunit-app-config-files-its-all-about-the-nunit-file/